# best way to call C# web service from PHP

Tags: c#, php, json, web-services, soap

I have form in PHP, and I should generate some data from form and send it to c# web service. What is the best way to call my c# web service method from PHP web site? This is my C# web service

```
public string Methode1(string Par1, int Par2, List<String> par3)
```

My list Par3 should contain few thousand elements. Should I use JSON or should I make an array in PHP and send it to C# via SOAP call? How should I create request?

What if connection drops, what will happen to request in JSON or in SOAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently used PHP to call a C# ServiceStack service.  it goes like this:

```
$content = json_encode($yourServiceMethodsArgumentShapeInstance);


$curl = curl_init($endpointUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$jsonResponse = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Can you tell me if this is REST or SOAP call? Thank you.

Comment: @DukaNikolau It would be classified as REST (using a loose interpretation of that acronym).

Comment: How should I create this object $yourServiceMethodsArgumentShapeInstance, if I have to pick data from 2 textboxes and one array?

Comment: That depends on the server-side implementation, really.  If you write the service to accept JSON, then you just use that.  `ServiceStack` makes it really easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

The same will happen to either. A request is just an HTTP request. The *contents* of the response contains either a SOAP message or any other content, which may be JSON. If you receive a half message, you probably cannot parse it, regardless whether it contains JSON or a SOAP XML message.

Personally I'm not a big fan of SOAP and would rather choose a REST interface, based on JSON.

Comment: Also personal, but I agree. I choose REST over SOAP every time +1

Comment: Is there any way to use some kind of transaction, so the user can be sure that all data is sent to web service?

Comment: Hardly. There are good failover measurements in TCP itself, but apart from that, no. Best thing you can do, is try to parse the results. Both XML and JSON are invalid if the last character is missing. In that case you can throw an error or execute the request again. But usually you will have either a successful request, or a timeout (which can be caught easily) or a server side error which results in a 500 status code. I don't know of any case where I received a response that seemed to be OK at first and then turned out to be cut-off.